# Word for the dimension of the vector space in which a vector lives?

Tags: linear-algebra, vocabulary

The following issue comes up whenever I teach linear algebra: I want to have a quick way to say that a vector $(x,y,z)$ is in $\mathbb{R}^3$. I am tempted to say that it has "length $3$". But then some student interprets this as saying that $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} = 3$. Is there some word other than "length" I could introduce and use to consistently refer to the number of coordinates in a vector? (To point out that I am not nuts here, the commands to get this number in [Mathematica](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Length.html) and [MATLAB](http://matlab.izmiran.ru/help/techdoc/ref/length.html) are `Length[]` and `length()`.)

Comment: Would "dimension" do?

Comment: This notion is extrinsic; there is no way to look at an object and tell 'the' vector space it belongs to (and one has stuff like $\mathbb{R}^{2n} \simeq \mathbb{C}^n$).  But seconded, maybe 'of real dimension 3' or 'real 3-tuple' might do.

Comment: I would also use dimension, but if the vector is known to sit inside some proper subspace I might also use "ambient dimension" to indicate how many components it has.

Comment: @user683: $n$-vector has the unfortunate collision with [certain physics terminology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-vector).

Comment: More to the point of the question itself: which kind of linear algebra course are you teaching? Is this an abstract linear algebra course, or an engineering one? What is your main perspective in terms of identifying an $n$-dimensional vector space over the field $\mathbb{F}$ with the space of $n$-tuples $\mathbb{F}^n$? I ask because the programming conventions are implicitly fixing a basis and always identifying vectors with tuples, hence the `length()`.

Comment: If you are drawing on programming languages for inspiration, the word `size` also is used. [MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html); [the Javascript framework JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202601/array-size-vs-array-length); [C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/size/).

Comment: @WillieWong while "$n$-vector" is used in physics for $n=4$ (and I suspect *only* for $n = 4$, so no variable gets used in the physics terminology context), I don't think the idea of using that label for a vector with $n$ components in a linear algebra course is going to confuse anyone studying physics. Two virtues of the term "$n$-vector" for a vector with $n$ components is that it is *short* and it won't be confused with anything else in a math class. Since this comment is 3 years after the original question, I wonder what David eventually decided to use in his linear algebra teaching.

Comment: @KCd: David's question specifically gives an example where a concrete number is used (n = 3). My comment points out that if you talk about n-vectors, then for the concrete case of 4 there is a terminology collision. As he never responded to my question about the context, I am not sure what kind of a linear algebra class it is. But if it is one that talks about the length of a concrete tuple, I suspect 3 and 4 will occur quite  a bit in examples.

Answer (score 6):

Along with "dimension", you could also use "component".
A vector in three dimensions has three components.

Answer (score 5):

I say "This is a 3D vector" or "This is a 7D vector".

Comment: I feel compelled to comment that this is used in a social context in which we are working on some problem involving some vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, where these vectors are being thought of as lists of numbers.  I certainly wouldn't use this terminology if I was talking about a vector living in an arbitrary vector space.

Answer (score 5):

If all your spaces are $\mathbb{R}^n$ then you can say n-dimensional (three-dimensional for $\mathbb{R}^3$). However the space of matrices $\displaystyle \left(\begin{array}{cc}a&b\\c&d\end{array}\right)$ ($a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{C}$) is four-dimensional over $\mathbb{C}$, eight-dimensional over $\mathbb{R}$ and infinite-dimensional over $\mathbb{Q}$. So be clear what the base field is. Alternatively you could just write $(a,b,c)\in\left(\mathbb{R}^3,+,\cdot\right)$ or more briefly $(a,b,c)\in\mathbb{R}^3$.